# Enable Set Audit Feild Permission programatically? Otherwise a block for SFDX CICD

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, cicd

I am not sure if there is other way but I can only enable the 'Set Audit Field' Permission through User Interface first, then assign Permission Set. I understand the reason Saleforce to do so.

While I am currently migrate my company's Project into SFDX, everything works find when I do some pre-requisite manually. Block comes when I want to set up the CICD pipeline, like auto create Scratch Org, and Push Metadata, then Auto Run Unit Test.

As one of our Class has a method in which assign CreatedDate and CreatedBy to a record. Unit test passed and all good in traditional development process as running user has correctly permissions, which is Set these fields.

But in a clean Scratch Org, running user wouldn't have such permission if we don't manually enable the permission and set the permset.

In unit test, I can definitely use Test.SetCreatedDate(), but this is only for CreatedDate field, I might can use something like

```
if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
   Test.setCreatedDate(xx, xxx); 
} else {
   x.CreatedDate = xxx.xxx;
}
```

but definitely not CreatedBy Field

any suggestion? Otherwise I have to exclude this class out of my sfdx folder.

Answer (score 0):

### From an existing repo and scratch org

1. In the source org

   - Run `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Settings:Security`
   - Search the retrieved file for `enableAuditFieldsInactiveOwner` and set the value to `true`. Save the file.
2. In a new scratch org

   - Run `sfdx force:source:deploy -m Settings:Security` **immediately** after creating the scratch org
   - Run `sfdx force:source:push` as usual
   - If needed, assign any needed permission sets using `sfdx force:user:permset:assign --permsetname [yourauditfieldpermset]`

### Why should this work?

Basically, you need to enable the `set audit fields` setting for the org **before** you attempt to add it to any permission sets or profiles. If you try to enable the setting and push the permission set at the same time, it'll fail silently--the rest of the permission set will go through, but not that piece.

[Here's a public repo with sample files.](https://github.com/allisonletts/sfdx-audit-fields-sample/blob/master/README.md)